# how to customize the marker using leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am adding markers to the map as below:

```
var markers = new L.LayerGroup();
L.marker([Latitude], [Longitude]).bindPopup("Hi there").addTo(markers);
map.addLayer(markers);
```

I have my own marker icons.Can someone tell me how to add those icons rather than default.....

Comment: Downvote: I am not a fan of answering with “read the docs”, but there is [a limit](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#icon) to draw somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var markers = new L.LayerGroup();   
 var myIcon = L.icon({ 
        iconUrl: 'my-icon.png', // pull out values as desired from the feature feature.properties.style.externalGraphic.
        iconSize: [38, 95],
        iconAnchor: [22, 94],
        popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
        shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
        shadowSize: [68, 95],
        shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
    });

    marker = L.marker([50.505, 30.57], {icon: myIcon}).bindPopup("Hi there").addTo(markers);;
map.addLayer(markers);
```